# Setting up reducer with typescript react redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-redux

I am setting up ts with redux and running into quite a number of issues - mostly down to my lack of knowledge, but cannot find much online. The error I am seeing is the following:

> Operator '+' cannot be applied to types 'CounterState' and '1'.

The code I have is as follows:

```
interface CounterState {
  state: number;
}

const initialState: CounterState = {
  state: 0
}

interface Action {
  type: string;
}

export const counterReducer = (state = initialState, action: Action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'INCREMENT':
      return state + 1;
    case 'DECREMENT':
      return state - 1;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

If I update to this it works but it seems like I don't have to define a type for the state. The following works

```
const initialState = 0;
interface Action {
  type: string;
}

export const counterReducer = (state = initialState, action: Action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'INCREMENT':
      return state + 1;
    case 'DECREMENT':
      return state - 1;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Comment: Your state is not a number. The state in your example code is an object with a property state. Instead just let CounterState be a number. (not an object), then it will work.
E.g. `type CounterState = number; const initialState = 0;`

Comment: that works, thanks! bit confused as I thought I also had to give the state a type earlier too.Updated the question

Comment: Well you "should" give it a type. Now the state type will be inferred from the initialState. It works but it's cleaner to define it. IMO. 
Theese guys have some good patterns https://github.com/piotrwitek/react-redux-typescript-guide#reducers

Comment: would you like to add an answer as to how it should be set up. Points are there for you ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's good practise to always strongly type your reducers, both state and actions.

Here i show an example of how a proper defined reducer and store can look like together. 
Hope this example together with my comments helps you.

```
import { Reducer } from "redux"; //This is just a Type we import from Redux.

interface IncrementAction {
  type: "INCREMENT"; //Define your action names
}

interface DecrementAction {
  type: "DECREMENT"; //Define your action names
}

type PossibleCounterActions = IncrementAction | DecrementAction; 
// The actions could/should be defined in another file for clarity


type CounterState = number;

const defaultState = 0;

// We bind the variable counterReducer to the Reducer type taken from redux.
// The our reducer code gets cleaner and we know the return type and arguments.
const counterReducer: Reducer<CounterState, PossibleCounterActions> = (state = defaultState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'INCREMENT':
      return state + 1;
    case 'DECREMENT':
      return state - 1;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}



// PS. This is not part of the question but it's
// a nice side-effect you can do when you have properly defined reducers.
// In the file where you create your store you can now get your store
// interface from the returntype of the redcuers using this pattern. 
const reducers = {
  counter: counterReducer
};

// Now we can get the entire store state from the declaration in the reducers.
export type IStoreState = { [k in keyof (typeof reducers)]: ReturnType<(typeof reducers)[k]> };

//More code to initialize your store.....
```